# Adding if function to check word group selected by randomizing function

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a tool that automatically formats some random passages of a text bold as well as underlined. My problem now is that sometimes it happens that words are both underlined and bold which i want to prevent. My first function selects a random text passage between 1-5 words and makes them bold which is fine. The next function defines another group of words from the now partly bold text. Here i want to add my if function. It should check if the words selected by the underline function are already bold and if so, it should make the underline function repeat the step of selecting words for so long until it finds words which are not bold yet.

Here is the script I am working with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(function() {
    function bold() {
        var target = document.getElementById("randomText");
        var oldHTML = target.innerHTML;
        for (j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
            target = document.getElementById("randomText");
            oldHTML = target.innerHTML;
            for (j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
                words = oldHTML.split(" ");
                wordCount = words.length;
                var newHTML = "";
                var highlightStart = Math.floor(Math.random() * wordCount) + 1;
                var highlightLength = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
                for (i = 0; i < wordCount; i++) {
                    if (i == highlightStart) newHTML = newHTML + "<b>";
                    newHTML = newHTML + words[i] + " ";
                    if (i == highlightStart + highlightLength) newHTML = newHTML + "</b>";
                    target.innerHTML = newHTML;
                }
                oldHTML = newHTML;
            }
        };
    };

    function underline() {
        var target = document.getElementById("randomText");
        var oldHTML = target.innerHTML;
        for (j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
            target = document.getElementById("randomText");
            oldHTML = target.innerHTML;
            for (j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
                words = oldHTML.split(" ");
                wordCount = words.length;
                var newHTML = "";
                var highlightStart = Math.floor(Math.random() * wordCount) + 1;
                var highlightLength = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
                for (i = 0; i < wordCount; i++) {
                    if (i == highlightStart) newHTML = newHTML + "<u>";
                    newHTML = newHTML + words[i] + " ";
                    if (i == highlightStart + highlightLength) newHTML = newHTML + "</u>";
                    target.innerHTML = newHTML;
                }
                oldHTML = newHTML;
            }
        };
    };

    $('#randomText').load('hier.txt', function () { bold(); underline(); });
})



});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it will be better if you make every word with the bold tag `<b>word_to_be_bolded</b>` then you can check at the start of the for loop in the `underline()` function using the string find function and recursively call the `underline()` function again.

Here is the requested code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(function() {
        function bold() {
            var target = document.getElementById("randomText");
            var oldHTML = target.innerHTML;
            for (j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
                target = document.getElementById("randomText");
                oldHTML = target.innerHTML;
                for (j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
                    words = oldHTML.split(" ");
                    wordCount = words.length;
                    var newHTML = "";
                    var highlightStart = Math.floor(Math.random() * wordCount) + 1;
                    var highlightLength = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
                    for (i = 0; i < wordCount; i++) {
                        var bolded_word = "<b>"+words[i]+"</b>";
                        newHTML = newHTML + bolded_word + " ";
                        if (i == highlightStart + highlightLength){
                            target.innerHTML = newHTML;
                        }
                    }
                    oldHTML = newHTML;
                }
            }
        }

        function underline() {
            var target = document.getElementById("randomText");
            var oldHTML = target.innerHTML;
            for (j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
                target = document.getElementById("randomText");
                oldHTML = target.innerHTML;
                for (j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
                    words = oldHTML.split(" ");
                    wordCount = words.length;
                    var newHTML = "";
                    var highlightStart = Math.floor(Math.random() * wordCount) + 1;
                    var highlightLength = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
                    for (i = 0; i < wordCount; i++) {
                        if(words[i].contains("<b>") > 0 || words[i].contains("</b>") > 0){
                            underline();
                        }
                        else{
                            if (i == highlightStart) newHTML = newHTML + "<u>";
                            newHTML = newHTML + words[i] + " ";
                        }
                        if (i == highlightStart + highlightLength) newHTML = newHTML + "</u>";
                        target.innerHTML = newHTML;
                    }
                    oldHTML = newHTML;
                }
            }
        }


        $('#randomText').load('hier.txt', function () { bold(); underline(); });
      })
    });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you have any idea how i could change my existing functio to do so?

Comment: @LP3813 please check the code and let me know if any help it needs changes.